# Need to add vertical space in Index entries

Tags: indexing, add-vertical-space

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[executive,twoside, justified, symmetric, notoc, openany]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc, name = Rindex, title = Index of R and RStudio, columns=2]
\newcommand{\Rindex}[1]{\index[Rindex]{#1}}
\begin{document}

The upper-left window\Rindex{window} is the \Rindex{R script}, which
is where we write and run code\Rindex{run code}, giving R commands to
execute\Rindex{execute}.


The lower-left\Rindex{lower-left} window is the \Rindex{R console},
where R provides either the results of successfully executed code (known as outputs) or any error\Rindex{error} messages.\Rindex{R errors}

\printindex[Rindex]

\end{document}
```

It's working fine, but need to insert some vertical space between particular entries only (not for all), please advise...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the manual, about `\indexsetup`:

[image]

With an exaggerated amount of `\parskip`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[intoc, name = Rindex, title = Index of R and RStudio, columns=2]
\indexsetup{othercode=\setlength{\parskip}{4ex plus 0.2ex minus 0.1ex}}

\newcommand{\Rindex}[1]{\index[Rindex]{#1}}

\begin{document}

The upper-left window is the \Rindex{R script}, which is where 
we write and run code, giving R commands to execute.


The lower-left window is the \Rindex{R console}, where R provides 
either the results of successfully executed code (known as outputs) 
or any error messages.\Rindex{R errors}

\printindex[Rindex]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir `egreg,` given suggestion is working fine globally but I need to increase the vertical space before a particular entry only not for global...Please advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Sorry, I don’t get it.

Comment: Have updated my question with clear picture, hope this helps you can understand the issue in a better way...Sorry for my `English`...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Sorry, but it doesn't make sense to me. What *rule* specifies when a space should be added? Without that, it's impossible to do anything.